# "will-change: left" seems doesn't trigger repainting

Tags: html, css, animation

As we all know, to display something on a webpage, the browser has to go through the following sequential steps:

- Style
- Layout
- Paint
- Composite

and transform and opacity are the only CSS properties that do not trigger repaint

Here the following sample code:

```html
<body>
<style>
    #a, #b {
     width: 100px;  
     height: 100px;  
     position: absolute;
     border: 1px solid
    }
    
    #a {
     background-color: red;   
     left: 10px;
     top: 10px;
     z-index: 2;
    }
    
    #b {
     background-color: green;   
     left: 50px;
     top: 50px;
     z-index: 1;
     animation: move 10s linear;
     will-change: left;
    }
    
    @keyframes move {
        from { left: 30px; }
        to { left: 100px; }
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I add the attribute "will-change: left" to force creating a new layer

2. In the rendering tab of Chrome Dev tools, I check on the "Paint flashing";
3. Although I animate the "left" attribute, it seems repainting did not happen, why?

Comment: What would be the result?

Comment: I think its exactly because you add `will-change: left` which creates new layer and tells browser to expect changes to `left` attribute and optimise for that
you can also check on number of paints if you select the layer in the layers tab in chrome dev tools

Comment: @paulitto i think that animate the "left" attribute would trigger paint, so everytime the anmiation data change, repaint should happen; is it right; but in my test, repaint only happen once in the start of the animation;

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense if the browser has to optimise the `left` property? If it really optimises it should act like a transform I guess?